# Averaging two dataframes without deleting missing in r

Tags: dataset, mean

i'm currently trying to merge two dataframes of technical replicates, and am stuck in trying to get my code to not clear missing values. For instance, I have:

df1

```
sampleID    geneID    ct
B1          GABBR1    26.5
B1          GABBR2    21.2
B1          GABRA1    NA
B1          GABRA2    19.0
```

and

df2

```
sampleID    geneID    ct
B1          GABBR1    26.1
B1          GABBR2    21.9
B1          GABRA1    14.7
B1          GABRA2    18.7
```

I have been able to combine and average the two dataframes using the following code:

```
  rbindlist(list(df1,df2))[,lapply(.SD,mean), list(sampleID, geneID)]
```

However, this then produces NA for the CT value on line 3. Is there any way I can alter this code so that it produces 14.7 instead?

EDIT: And if anyone knows of a better way to combine technical replicates than this somewhat brutish manner, i'm all ears for that too!

Answer (score 1):

`mean` function always returns NA if you don't specify `na.rm=TRUE`.

In order to calculate the mean (or whatever statistic value) I suggest you to use:

```
rbindlist(list(df1,df2))[,lapply(.SD,mean, na.rm=TRUE), list(sampleID, geneID)]
```

This will NOT DELETE NA VALUES, it just not going to take into account.

Comment: Thanks for the help Dave. I have tried it this way, and it didn't do exactly what I wanted. What I really want is that if i'm taking the mean of two values, one of which is missing, it returns the value of the non-missing value. For e.g. when averaging 14.7 and NA, I want it to return 14.7. Any idea?

Comment: At the step that you want to calculate that average, put na.rm=TRUE.
Check this two lines: mean(c(14.7, NA)) //// mean(c(14.7, NA), na.rm=TRUE)

Comment: I see what you mean and this is exactly what i'm looking for. But it doesn't seem to work in the above code. It juts produces NaN instead of Na :/

Comment: Please, show me the code part that produces you Nan.